# How to escape 3 level in bash (su command, psql, then query)

Tags: bash, escaping, psql, su

I'm working on a bash script used to install an application on a server and create a postgresql user for the application.

The matter is that if the user contains a special char, it's not escaped. So I would like to escape the name in the query.

Here is a part of my code:

```
db_user="test-test"
db_password=1234
su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE USER $db_user WITH PASSWORD '$db_password';\""
```

So I have to escape:

- the command for `su -c ...`
- the query for `psql -c ...`
- the user name in `$db_user`
- the password in `$db_password`

Of course, if I add quotes around $db_user it's not working anymore. I tried others solutions, but none working.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen if someone specifies that they want their password to be `'; DROP TABLE USERS; -- '`?

Comment: ...or perhaps of a password of `s33kret'; ALTER ROLE myname WITH SUPERUSER; --`

Comment: ...that said, if you want the starting user to be able to run PostgreSQL queries with superuser privileges, maybe it makes more sense to just configure postgres to do that natively, vs changing OS-level privileges with `su`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `sudo -u postgres psql -c '...'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the shell do the work for you for you. In this case, that means `printf '%q'` -- which returns an `eval`-safe version of each literal argument.

```
cmd=( psql -c "CREATE USER $db_user WITH PASSWORD '$db_password';" )
printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"
su - postgres -c "$cmd_q"
```

By the way, substituting literal text into SQL queries this way is massively insecure -- but if you follow the process above you're prone to only SQL injection bugs, not shell injection bugs.

---

To avoid SQL injection bugs as well, you want to avoid textual substitution of values into your queries at all.

```
# This is inefficient, but makes it completely unambiguous that our heredocs are literal
query=$(cat <<'EOF'
CREATE USER :new_user_name WITH PASSWORD :'new_user_password';
EOF
)

cmd=(
  psql \
    --set=new_user_name="$db_user" \
    --set=new_user_password="$db_password"
    -c "$query"
)

printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"
su - postgres -c "$cmd_q"
```

See http://caryrobbins.com/dev/postgres-scripting/ for more on this technique. The classic XKCD linked in its header (also useful as a concrete example of the risks the original code was taking!) has its original source at https://xkcd.com/327/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it ! In your first solution, just add \" around $db_user and it's perfect.